# Как импортировать файл пакетом __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть 2 дирректории:

`Doctor_Bot/config/hidden.py`

и

`Doctor_Bot/bot_start/script.py`

**hidden.py:**

```py
token = 'Токен'
```

**script.py:**

```py
from config.hidden import token
print(hidden.token)
```

**Ошибка:**

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'

Я понимаю что надо смотреть в сторону `__init__.py`, дабы сделать из папки пакет, но как правильно его применить я понять не могу.

Вот скриншоты самого кода и иерархии папок:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python определяет пути для модулей в переменной path. Вам нужно добавить в path путь к родительской папке, откуда можно будет импортировать модуль config.

```
from sys import path
    
path.append(path[0].replace(path[0].split('\\')
           [len(path[0].split('\\')) - 1], ''))

from config.hidden import token
```

Comment: Да, действительно решение подошло. Но нет ли способа через __init__ файл вывести переменную токен. Не уверен что достаточно понятно изъяснился поэтому для наглядности оставлю видео:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEj4J0y4GwU
Таймкод: 2:15

P.S. Я не к тому, что решение является плохим, а исключительно из любопытства. Имеет ли право на жизнь тот способ, который был указан в видео, и если имеет, то как его правильно реализовать?

Comment: __init__.py превращает папку в пакет, но в версиях Python 3 и выше этот __init__.py уже необязателен. Т.е. папка config уже является пакетом и вы её импортируете. А моё решение нужно лишь для того, чтобы указать путь к родительской папке, откуда можно будет импортировать пакет (папку) config. Попробуйте переложить файл script.py из папки bot_start в папку doctor_bot и без path.append просто импортировать config. Тогда ошибки ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config' возникать не будет.

Answer (score 3):

При вашей структуре файлов (все лежит в папке `Doctor_Bot`), чтобы все файлы друг к другу могли обращаться через импорт, сама папка `Doctor_Bot` должна считаться общим пакетом.

Тогда нужно заменить импорты, например, на относительные :

```
from ..config.hidden import token
```

или абсолютные, с указанием основного пакета:

```
from Doctor_Bot.config.hidden import token
```

И запускать вашего бота извне пакета через

```
python -m Doctor_Bot.bot_start.script
```

Но в этом случае удобнее было бы, чтобы папкой проекта была не сама папка `Doctor_Bot`, а папка на уровень выше. Для удобства запуска снаружи `Doctor_Bot` можно создать пусковой файл такого вида:

`run.py`

```
import Doctor_Bot.bot_start.script
```

Скриншот, в терминале первый запуск через "треугольник" в файле run.py, второй - просто через командную строку без пускового файла:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]